# how do I get user email and full name using instagram graph api

Tags: instagram-graph-api

I'm using a consumer facebook developer account. I need to get user media information from the following endpoint. Particularly need to get **user full name, email and profile picture url**

**Request:**

```
https://graph.instagram.com/{user-id}?fields=id,username,account_type,media_count&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

```
{
  id: "3454354543543345",
  username: "test",
  account_type: "PERSONAL",
  media_count: 22
}
```

Referred from the doc: [getting-profile-info](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-profiles-and-media) [user-fields](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user)

Answer (score 0):

If just Graph API only, I am afraid email and profile picture are not possible at this stage.

And now they even make it more restrict by forbidding people from accessing the account data json via API call, which was originally one major way people use to access to user's profile picture url.